# from datagridview to chart C# doubling the first row

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, datagridview

I have a script that at some point creates a chart from a DataGrid, this DataGrid contains 3 columns: now the problem is that when the chart is generated the first row is always getting doubled and puts it in between all the other bars in the chart.

Example - Let's say if the chart should be A-B-C however, instead of A-A-B -A-C like wise.

Refer to screenshot here - [resulting chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U672.jpg)

The source code I used is this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) 
 {
  this.chart1.Series["Spent hr"].Points.AddXY(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()));
  this.chart1.Series["Budgeted hr"].Points.AddXY(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have no idea why this works but adding this code just after the initialisation of the for cycle resolved the issue, it was not only the first row bein duplicated but every rows after it was put in:

```
                        if (i == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
                        {
                            foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
                            {
                                series.Points.Clear();
                            }

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out -

```
    // filling the columns
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("name", "Column1");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("budgetedhr", "Column2");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("spenthr", "Column3");

    // filling in Rows with some data
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Jhon", 21, 23);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Nicol", 31, 2);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Matteo", 23, 41);

    // Now we can set up the Chart:
    List<Color> colors = new List<Color> { Color.Green, Color.Red};

    chart1.Series.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Series S = chart1.Series.Add(dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString());
        S.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        S.Color = colors[i];
    }

    // and fill in all the values from the dgv to the chart:
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            int p = chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText, dataGridView1[j, i].Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this one is giving me a couple of problem, in the end i just cleared the whole chart just before the last row, only problem is that as a newbie...i have no idea why it worked.